# Pre-Populate an edit form with WTForms and Flask

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms, flask-bootstrap

I am able to add a new entry to my database using WTForms and Flask and I can edit too, the problem is that I need to display the already existing information in the database in an edit form.

I have the following code:

## A Class For the Edit Post Form

```
class editPostForm(Form):
    postTitle = TextField('postTitle', validators.Required()])
    postSubtitle = TextField('postSubtitle', validators.Required()])
```

## A Route for the Edit Post Template

```
@app.route('/editpost/<postId>', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def editpost_page(postId):
try:
    form = editPostForm(form)

    if request.method == "POST" and form.validate():
        postTitle = form.postTitle.data
        postSubtitle = form.postSubtitle.data

        c, conn = connection()

        query = c.execute("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_id = (%s)",
                          [noinjection(postId)])

        c.execute("UPDATE posts SET post_title=%s, post_subtitle=%s WHERE post_id = %s",
                     [
                     noinjection(postTitle),
                     noinjection(postSubtitle),
                     noinjection(postId)
                     ])

        conn.commit()

        flash("Post Edited", 'success')

        c.close()
        conn.close()
        gc.collect()

        return redirect(url_for('posts'))

    return render_template("editpost.html", form = form, POST_ID = postId)

except Exception as e:
    return(str(e))
```

## The Edit Post Template {jinja}

```
{% extends "header.html" %}

{% block body %}

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <br />
        <h4>Edit Post</h4>
        <br />
        {% from "_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}
        <form action="/editpost/{{ POST_ID }}" class="form-horizontal" method="post">
            {% from "_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}
            <form action="/editpost/" method="post">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="postTitle">Post Title</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="postTitle" name="postTitle" placeholder="Post Title" value="{{request.form.postTitle}}">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="postSubtitle">Post Subtitle</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="postSubtitle" name="postSubtitle" placeholder="Post Subtitle" value="{{request.form.postSubtitle}}">
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </form>
            {% if error %}
                <p class="error"><strong>Error: </strong>{{error}}</p>
            {% endif %}
        </form>
        {% if error %}
            <p class="error"><strong>Error: </strong>{{error}}</p>
        {% endif %}

    </div>
</body>

{% endblock %}
```

With the following code, I am getting a selected post to update in the database, but the editpost template is not showing the values which are already in the database and all the fields are blank.

How can I pre-populate the form before editing?

Comment: Yes but the manual is referring to an object, which I don't know how to use. Maybe I need to learn how to set that object but I cannot seem to find the proper information on how to create the object with the data, or I'm not using the right keywords to search online.

Comment: Did you really mean `form = editPostForm(form)`?  Seems like you're referencing `form` before assignment.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can populate each field separately like this:

```
form = editPostForm(form)
form.postTitle.data = postTitle_from_database
form.postSubtitle.data = postSubtitle_from_database
```

or you can populate your form fields from a given object using `process` method:

> `process(formdata=None, obj=None, **kwargs)`
>
> Take form, object data, and keyword arg input and have the fields
>   process them.
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> - formdata – Used to pass data coming from the enduser, usually    request.POST or equivalent.
> - obj – If formdata has no data for a    field, the form will try to get it from the passed object.
> - **kwargs – If neither formdata or obj contains a value for a field, the form will assign the value of a matching keyword argument
>     to the field, if provided.
>
> Since BaseForm does not take its data at instantiation, you must call
>   this to provide form data to the enclosed fields. Accessing the
>   field’s data before calling process is not recommended.

Comment: Ty for `form.postTitle.data` !

Answer (score 6):

I was able to pre-populate HTML `input` and `textarea` fields from a SQL database with Python and Jinja as follows:

**1. Store relevant data from database in a variable:**

```
    name = db.execute("""SELECT name FROM users WHERE id = :id""", id=session["user_id"])

    about = db.execute("""SELECT about FROM users WHERE id = :id""", id=session["user_id"])
```

**2. Render template (with render_template function) and pass in the relevant variables:**

`return render_template("edit.html", name = name, about = about)`

**3. Pass variables via jinja to html `input` and `textarea` elements. Index into the object that has been passed as follows:**

For an `input` tag use the value attribute as below:

```
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{ name[0]["name"] }}">
```

For a `textarea` element:

```
    <textarea class="form-control" name="about">{{ about[0]["about"] }}</textarea>
```